# CiviCRM Log shows error invoking Payment Form

Tags: drupal

Periodically I seem to have the following error on my CiviCRM site. I have never actually seen the error and have had a hard time tracking it down. I would be interested if anyone could point me to steps I need to take to reproduce the error (get the civicrm_invoke(payment, form) method to fire so that I might see what is happening. It seems odd that line #2 shows a null value for the name. I only have one processor_id installed (Stripe). Any pointers for tracking down further what is happening here would be appreciated.

```
May 12 08:19:43  [info] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/isi/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(378): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/isi/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Type.php(476): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("processor_id (value: ) is not of the type Integer")
#2 /var/www/isi/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Request.php(110): CRM_Utils_Type::validate("", "Integer", TRUE, "processor_id")
#3 /var/www/isi/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Financial/Form/Payment.php(55): CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve("processor_id", "Integer", NULL, TRUE)
#4 /var/www/isi/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(549): CRM_Financial_Form_Payment->preProcess()
#5 /var/www/isi/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#6 /var/www/isi/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Financial_Form_Payment), "display")
#7 /var/www/isi/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Financial_Form_Payment), "display")
#8 /var/www/isi/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#9 /var/www/isi/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#10 /var/www/isi/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(284): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Financial_Form_Payment", NULL, NULL)
#11 /var/www/isi/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#12 /var/www/isi/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#13 /var/www/isi/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#14 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("payment", "form")
#15 /var/www/isi/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#16 /var/www/isi/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#17 {main}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's getting an error when loading the payment-processor specific part of a contribution form, via AJAX. It should be getting the payment processor id as part of the ajax call, but it's not. That suggests it might be on an old contribution page that had a payment processor configured as an option that is no longer available.

If you can look at your web server access logs and find the corresponding contribution page you might identify the problem. It's even possible that you wouldn't actually see an error on your form, it would only show up in your console.

Comment: really helpful! thanks